# How do I import tab separated data into R when it is broken up by additional information?

Tags: r

I have data from one long .result file in the following structure:

```
#Stuff I don't need
>good information1
header1     header2    header3
1     2     3
1     2     3
1     2     3

#################
#Stuff I don't need (next dataset)
>good information2
header1     header2    header3
4     5     6
4     5     6
4     5     6
```

I would like to read this data into a data frame where the information after the # is removed and the tab separated data is joined into a long data frame. Ideally the information after > would be added as a column to designate where the data comes from. Something like the following:

```
header1     header2    header3     header 4
1     2     3     good information1
1     2     3     good information1
1     2     3     good information1
4     5     6     good information2
4     5     6     good information2
4     5     6     good information2
```

Comment: Not sure where your data begins, where it ends, if it's two files or one, which format etc.

Comment: Is the `>` actually there?

Comment: If you try to read from a single file, you may want `read.delim(file = "file", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE, comment.char = ">")` or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a lot of elbow-grease, but ...

Starting with a file with the contents of your first code block,

```r
rawlines <- readLines("path/to/file") |>
  grep("^#", x = _, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
rawlines
#  [1] ">good information1"             "header1     header2    header3" "1     2     3"                 
#  [4] "1     2     3"                  "1     2     3"                  ""                              
#  [7] ">good information2"             "header1     header2    header3" "4     5     6"                 
# [10] "4     5     6"                  "4     5     6"                 

goodinfo <- replace(rawlines, !nzchar(rawlines) | grepl("^[^>]", rawlines), NA) |>
  sub("^>", "", x = _) |>
  zoo::na.locf(na.rm = FALSE)
goodinfo
#  [1] "good information1" "good information1" "good information1" "good information1" "good information1"
#  [6] "good information1" "good information2" "good information2" "good information2" "good information2"
# [11] "good information2"

headerrow <- rawlines[grep("^>", rawlines)[1] + 1L]
headerrow
# [1] "header1     header2    header3"

keeprows <- !grepl("^>", rawlines) & nzchar(rawlines)
keeprows <- keeprows & c(keeprows[1], keeprows[-length(keeprows)])
keeprows
#  [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

tab <- read.table(text = paste(c(headerrow, rawlines[keeprows]), collapse = "\n"), header = TRUE)
tab$header4 <- goodinfo[keeprows]
tab
#   header1 header2 header3           header4
# 1       1       2       3 good information1
# 2       1       2       3 good information1
# 3       1       2       3 good information1
# 4       4       5       6 good information2
# 5       4       5       6 good information2
# 6       4       5       6 good information2
```

Answer (score 3):

The following works with the data as posted.
First it uses a `cumsum` trick to create a factor `f` telling the  groups of rows starting with a row where `">"` is the first character. Then it splits the data by `f` and creates the data.frames in a `lapply` loop. Finally, the df's are assembled together.

```
txt <- readLines("non_standard_file.txt")
grepl(">", txt) |> cumsum() -> f
split(txt, f) |>
  lapply(\(x) {
    y <- sub(">", "", x[1L])
    x <- x[-1L]
    if(length(x) > 0L) {
      tbl <- read.table(text = x, header = TRUE)
      new_col <- sprintf("header%d", ncol(tbl) + 1L)
      tbl[[new_col]] <- y
      tbl
    }
    else invisible(NULL)
  }) |>
  do.call(rbind, args = _)
```